# Thai Month names from cultureInfo returns empty string of array in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am using System.Globalization.CurrentInfo as "th-TH". But from System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.MonthNames I get an array of empty strings of Array. how do I get Thai Date Formats ?

Comment: Is the [Thai Bhuddist Calendar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.thaibuddhistcalendar?view=net-5.0) what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for Thai Bhuddist calendar.

Comment: Does that answer your question?